# counting users in db to equal users level

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count my users and then send a command to update a different table to change their displayed "Level" on their profile. Here's what I got....

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'ow_base_user'.'id' WHERE 'id'") or die (mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$count = $row[0];
$username = [userid];
$count = "";
$lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'empower' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =13; }
if ($count >= 2720) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'integrity' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =18; }
else if ($count >= 625) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'honor' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =17; }
else if ($count >= 125) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'passion' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =16; }
else if ($count >= 25) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'creative' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =15; }
else if ($count >= 5) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'inspire' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =14; }
?>
```

Comment: please wrap quotes around `$lvl`'s value also you have a few other syntax errors.

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting not tell you what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet above has several problems, lets start here..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'ow_base_user'.'id' WHERE 'id'") or die (mysql_error());
```

your where clause in the above statement is blank and this is not allowed in SQL

Futher in your snippet you have

```
$lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'empower' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =13; }
if ($count >= 2720) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'integrity' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =18; }
else if ($count >= 625) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'honor' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =17; }
else if ($count >= 125) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'passion' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =16; }
else if ($count >= 25) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'creative' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =15; }
else if ($count >= 5) { $lvl = UPDATE  `founda_Inspire`.`ow_base_authorization_role` SET  `name` =  'inspire' WHERE  `ow_base_authorization_role`.`id` =14; }
```

And your quotes are all in the wrong places so your SQL strings are not being built correctly

On a side note, you will generally get a better response on stackoverflow when you have shown an effort to solve your problems prior to posting.  Based on what you posted it seems like you just said "eh its not working let me ask on SO"